# Azure Function versus Data Factory pipeline, which do you recommend?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

We need to construct an application that runs once a month.

Its purpose is to pull data from a database and feed it to another database with the same schema, while doing some minor transformations to that data (nothing too intensive, though, mostly obfuscation).

We would like it to be as cost-effective as possible, since it's meant to help development, and doesn't bring any value to production. We would also require it run entirely on the cloud, since the values coming from the source database could be sensitive and should not go through any local machine.

Would you recommend we created an ADF pipeline for this, or an Azure function? Or something entirely different (as long as it is still an Azure service)? It wouldn't ever need to scale out or up, and performance doesn't really matter.

Also, we have developers who can handle the code, so the no-code or low-code options can be ruled out if they're not exactly better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADF pipeline has in built connectors to access the databases and a copy activity to copy the data.
In case if there are transformations involved, you can either copy the data as is in staging table and then leverage stored procedure to do transformations which would be cheaper as compared to leveraging a dataflow within ADF to incorporate minor transformations.